# Using long timestamp or Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a legacy Java application, where its performance bottle neck is due to the usage of Calendar. As Calendar is a mutable object, we have to clone every-time we get it.

```
public Calendar getCalendar() {
    return (Calendar)calendar.clone();
}
```

We also discover that in our application, we didn't use the time zone information at all. I was wondering, should we just re-factor the code to

```
public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
```

We will only turn the timestamp into Calendar or Joda DateTime, when we need to perform date/time arithmetic operation.

Or to prevent unforeseen future, should we use [Joda DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

```
public DateTime getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: LocalDateTime is the suitable class to use, not DateTime, if you do not have time zone info to store

Comment: @JodaStephen, I was wondering if in the future, I need TimeZone information, is the change will be cheap? (That's why I hesitate to use pure 'long'). If I just don't need time zone info, I will instead choose to use 'long', and use Java Calendar whenever there is arithmetic or comparison need.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if you don't care about timezone and you have to store a lot of timestamps, you'd better store them as long-s. It is 8 bytes per timestamp. All object oriented date-time wrappers around 'long' will consume at least 24 bytes per timestamp. When you'll need to perform any datetime arithmetic - convert your long timestamp into a Joda DateTime (or MutableDateTime). They are both implemented as wrappers around a 'long' field, so creating them from long is extremely cheap.

Comment: You mean as a `long` right? What do you mean by `long-s`? (Oh, I think you mean `long`s.)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use JodaTime.  Make sure you pass around your dates in java.util.Date, which is just a long number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 in UTC.